# pandas range(1, 4) vectorize the body

Tags: python, pandas, loops

This is my code (it IS homework - analyzing the titanic survivors data):

```
for Pclass in range(1, 4):
    select_df = df.loc[df["Pclass"] == Pclass, col]
    x_min = select_df.min()
    x_max = select_df.max()
    # possible ZeroDivisionError error if x_max = x_min
    df.loc[df["Pclass"] == Pclass, col] = (select_df - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
```

`PClass` is one of the columns with integer values 1, 2, and 3.

My **question** is how to do that without the for loop? Without three consecutive copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teacher answered:

Define an additional function to do the computation:

```
def f_normalisation(df, col):
    select_df = df.loc[:, col]
    x_min = select_df.min()
    x_max = select_df.max()
    # possible ZeroDivisionError error if x_max = x_min
    df.loc[:, col] = (select_df - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
    return df
```

Then apply the function to the dataframe grouped by `PClass`.

```
df.groupby("Pclass").apply(f_normalisation, col=col)
```